# print a big, landscape PDF drawing to a3 LaserJet4 (portrait) using ghostscript 9.0

Tags: linux, shell, printing, ghostscript

We want to print big drawings (up to A0 and some times longer) to A3 printers using ghostscript:

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r1200x1200 -sPAPERSIZE=a3 -f
/S/tmp/SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf | gs -o resized.pcl -sDEVICE=ljet4
-g7012x4961 -dPDFFitPage -
```

I get A4 landscape on an A3 portrait Paper. I also tried to rotate:

```
gs -sOutputFile="-" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r1200x1200 -sPAPERSIZE=a3 -d
-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFFitPage -c "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice 90 rotate 0 -595 translate" -f
/S/tmp/SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf -c quit | gs -o resized.pcl
-sDEVICE=ljet4 -g7012x4961 -dPDFFitPage -
```

getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

---

> ***gs -q -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=out.pcl -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a3 \
> -c "`<</Install {-1 -1 scale -843 -1192 translate}>>` setpagedevice"
>  -f SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf -c quit***

Comment: Yes, PDFFitPage is what I would have recommended. It auto-rotates and

Comment: (oops) centers to the page size when -dFIXEDMEDIA is used.

Answer (score 1):

Its not really possible to comment without seeing a PDF file, but a number of the command line options you are using there don't make sense in the combination you have.

The *first* thing I would do is stop piping the commands like that, at least while investigating the problem. Do it as 2 stages, that will allow you (and others) to look at the intermediate PDF file.

Secondly, I don't believe you can do what you seem to be trying to do. It looks like you are trying to pipe the PDF produced by the first invocation of gs through the second invocation. I don't see any way that will work, the pdfwrite device needs to seek around the file in order to create the xref table, it cannot use stdout, at least in the current version. What version of Ghostscript are you using ?

I also can't see the point of this, why take a PDF, make a new PDF from it, and then render the second PDF ? Why not just render the original ?

None of the media size switches you are specifying will have any effect, because you haven't told Ghostscript that the media size is fixed (using -dFIXEDMEDIA). As a result the PDF interpreter will set the media size to be the same as the MediaBox in the PDF file. Similar problems apply with sending PostScript and expecting it to alter the behaviour of Ghostscript when rendering a PDF file.

Setting the resolution for pdfwrite is not a good idea, and will in general have no effect. Even if it does have an effect, you probably don't want to set it to be the resolution of the device (and the -g values seem to suggest this is not a 1200 dpi device either). The only effect the resolution has is when objects have to be rendered to images because the can't be represented in PDF. You don't want to create images at the printer resolution, somewhere between one quarter and one half the resolution is usually sufficient.

If you'd care to share an example PDF file, I may be able to tell you how to solve your orientation problem. You will need to explain why you are running it through pdfwrite before going to PCL though, I can't see any reason for that.

This:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=\temp\out.pdf -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=2386.08 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1685.7600 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf
```

Will take your original PDF file and produce a PDF file rotated by 90 degrees. If I then do:

```
gs -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=\temp\out.pcl \temp\out.pdf
```

I get a PCL file that, when processed by GhostPDL with appropriate media size, seems to do what you want.

I haven't tried it, due to lack of an actual device to print on, but I would expect that:

```
gs -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=\temp\out.pcl -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=2386.08 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1685.7600 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf
```

would produce the same file in one step.

[image: This is the result]

Comment: I just found a way to convert my [PDF (DIN A1) to PCL (DIN A3)](https://transfer.doppelmayr.com/pickup.php?claimID=ijTpB4p8Hv9DebCv&claimPasscode=vPEwdCdEuiCCkPZD&emailAddr=hl%40doppelmayr.com)<br/>

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to edit the comment above.

@KenS: 
I just found a way to convert my [PDF (DIN A1) to PCL (DIN A3)](https://transfer.doppelmayr.com/pickup.php?claimID=KdfbPJobWy6AVGfA&claimPasscode=arwiguCD6ekXFmRH&emailAddr=hl%40doppelmayr.com)

gs -q -o - -sDEVICE=ljet4 -g9921x7015 -dPDFFitPage \
 -f /S/tmp/rot_a3.ps -f /S/tmp/SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf \
 | sed "s/l0o/l2o/" | sed "s/l-180u/l140u/" > testA3.pcl

rot_a3.ps for rotation also in download

Could I replace the sed hack directly in Ghostscript ?

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer because I can't format the comments.

Comment: I´ve added a picture of the result to @KenS´s answer, because I can´t add a pic to a comment.

Comment: Is that a picture of the PDF,or the resulting PCL, or something else ?

Comment: It is of the resulting PCL.

Comment: I suppose I should have asked, but is this the result of printing to your printer, or the result of running back through Ghostscript ? I'm not a PCL expert, so I can't really comment much on it.

Comment: With the 1. command (gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=\temp\out.pdf -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=2386.08 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1685.7600 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf), I get an portrait A1 with the drawing A1 landscape at the bottom.

Comment: With the 2. and 3. command I get an empty letter page.

The "result" was just a mistake of me.

Comment: Hmm, odd I definitely get a rotated PDF out of the first command, what version of GS are you using ?

Comment: gs version 9.0 (see header)

Comment: Oh, well I'm using the current version, 9.06. I don't have a copy of 9.0 to hand, though I would be surprised if it were any different in this regard. I'll see if I can locate the commit for 9.0

Comment: Intriguingly the 9.0 version did behave incorrectly for me. Not the same as your output, but still incorrect. I would suggest that you install 9.06

Comment: You are right v 9.06 is working: gs -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=out.pcl -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a3 SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf. But is it possible to rotate the output 180° ?

Comment: That would be more difficult, considerably more difficult, can't you just flip the paper after you've printed it ? :-)

Comment: flipping horizontal and vertical would to the trick. I think I have to use -1 -1 scale, but I don´t know how.

Comment: I found a solution:

gs -q -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=out.pcl -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a3 -c "<</Install {-1 -1 scale -843 -1192 translate}>> setpagedevice" -f SamplePDFnewStamp.pdf -c quit